# Android How to set the imageview in front of drawingview

Tags: android, graphics, imageview, drawing

I am using drawing view to draw on touch of user , So I need to put the image in front of it. There are some letters written in the middle of image , which is in translucent , while the other places are covered with color. So on touch the user would only see the letter filling with paint as the letter is transparent and translucent.

**Edited**

[image: this] is the picture, I want to fill the only white space with color on user touch. Right now I am painting on a white canvas and , truly I have copied the code of touch to draw from android api demo folder. So please Tell me How to fill that white blank space only .

I came up with idea and that is to draw canvas as the source code of api demo is doing , and just put the imageveiw in front of this canvas hence user would only see the white area is filling with color. Any idea that How can I perform this ?

So My major problem is how to put that image view in front canvas in android. ?

Comment: It will be helpful, If you can show us the drawing.

Comment: @anitha let me post a picture